# I need to serialize in Perl with PHP format

Tags: perl, serialization

I can serialize a hash with the PHP serialization format using **PHP::Serialization**.

```
$result = serialize({ a => 1111, b => 2222})
# IT GIVES ME 'a:2:{s:1:"a";i:1111;s:1:"b";i:2222;}';
```

BUT when values are strings I need them treated as strings, even if they look as numbers or dates.

```
$result = serialize({ a => '1111', b => '2222'});
# IT GIVES ME THE SAME 'a:2:{s:1:"a";i:1111;s:1:"b";i:2222;}';
```

And this is what I need:

```
# 'a:2:{s:1:"a";s:4:"1111";s:1:"b";s:4:"2222";}'
```

OK, Perl is very loosy about types, but if I say something is a string... shouldn't it be treated as a string?

**PHP::Serialization** has an option to treat double or float as strings, but integers, dates and so on, even when quoted recover its Perl type. I tried double and single quotes, also q(), qq(), qw(), but no luck. Even tricks like `"1111" . ""`.

I can't find an alternative in CPAN. Do I need to rewrite PHP::Serialization?

Comment: And here I was thinking PHP's type understanding was more loose than Perl's. :D

Comment: It's not Perl's looseness here, it's the PHP::Serialization module that makes assumptions without looking at Perl's data types. Perl knows the difference between `"1"` and `1` internally, but PHP::S just does a regex to check for numbers. See https://metacpan.org/source/BOBTFISH/PHP-Serialization-0.34/lib%2FPHP%2FSerialization.pm#L380

Comment: Your best bet imho is to subclass PHP::Serialization and replace the `encode` method with your own that does things differently.

Comment: Thank yot, that´s the line where the type decission is made. I am going to try it, because I do not have the courage to make my own parser.

Comment: No need to make your own parser. I have some more time now and I am happy to write an answer to outline what you have to do.

Comment: I did it succesfully removing the conditional from the plugin at that line, and leaving just the 'string' option. I hardwired it in the plugin. I'm goin to try your new answer, obviously nicer than mine.

Comment: If it's just for your code, hacking it works. But then you shouldn't do it in your main system lib directory, but create a patch, install that module locally and apply the patch. Otherwise if you update (and it's the system package manager rather than CPAN where you go it from) your changes will be overwritten. Also keep in mind other parts of your overall system might use that module (unlikely for this particular one though). Or you can just copy the whole thing, change the name, change the code. That works too. But then version it with your code.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to write your own parser. You can subclass PHP::Serialization. Or at least you can try.

My below implementation can be used as a drop-in for your example, but it has limits.

The module looks like it allows subclassing at first glance because the `serialize` and `deserialize` functions use `__PACKAGE__` to instantiate, and `new` uses `$class` too. But at closer inspection, there are a couple of lexical variables in the file scope that are basically isolated from a subclass. Therefore, some functionality is lost. You also don't inherit package variables like `@EXPORT_OK`, and in general the Exporter does not play totally well with OO code.

My code can be used as a drop-in replacement for your specific example, and I believe it can serialise data structures as long as they are not sorted. If you need `$sorthash` (which is the `$shash` arg to `encode`) you get into trouble, because the lexical one in the subclass is different from the one in the parent class, and there is no sane way to get it.

To make this work, we have to redefine `serialize` and export it.

I've put a very naive hack in to just treat everything that isn't a data structure or an object as a string, basically eliminating numbers.

```perl
package PHP::Serialization::MoreStringent;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Scalar::Util qw/blessed/;
use Carp qw(confess);

use parent 'PHP::Serialization';

# we need this so the non-OO functions can be exported
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(serialize);
sub serialize   { __PACKAGE__->new->encode(@_) }

# this thing is bad, because it's now lexical in our subclass - so it breaks
my $sorthash;

# this is mostly a copy of the original code
sub encode {
    my ($self, $val, $iskey, $shash) = @_;
    $iskey=0 unless defined $iskey;
    $sorthash=$shash if defined $shash;

    if ( ! defined $val ) {
        return $self->_encode('null', $val);
    }
    elsif ( blessed $val ) {
        return $self->_encode('obj', $val);
    }
    elsif ( ! ref($val) ) {
        # very naive hack to make all other things into string
        return $self->_encode('string', $val);
    }
    else {
        my $type = ref($val);
        if ($type eq 'HASH' || $type eq 'ARRAY' ) {
            return $self->_sort_hash_encode($val) if (($sorthash) and ($type eq 'HASH'));
            return $self->_encode('array', $val);
        }
        else {
            confess "I can't serialize data of type '$type'!";
        }
    }
}

1;
```

Now we can run this with the following test, and it at least produces the output you want.

```perl
use Test::More;
use PHP::Serialization::MoreStringent 'serialize';

is serialize({ a => 1111, b => 2222}), 'a:2:{s:1:"a";s:4:"1111";s:1:"b";s:4:"2222";}';

done_testing;
```

I have not tested it with data structures because I have no idea what they should look like in PHP's serialisation format. I have deliberately removed the deserialisation because that makes heavy use of this `$sorthash` variable, so we have basically broken it. I think.

However the concept should be clear.

---

As an alternative, could you just post-process the output and regex the quotes in?